# I tf.gfile.DeleteRecursively the wrong directory, is there a way to restore it ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, delete-directory

I was running the https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py example .

And I set my log directory as ~/ and deleted some very important stuff. 
Is there a way to restore those files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. A reminder to *always* have a backup.